# Is there a method to select or create options for dropdown in OctoberCMS backend forms?

Tags: backend, octobercms, octobercms-backend, octobercms-widgets

I want to create a category field where the user can select one the unique values already typed or create a unique category their own. Is there any method to do this in OctoberCMS? I went through the form-field types and checked the dropdown options. But couldn't find anything. Is there any plugin to do this at least?

Comment: @HardikSatasiya Yes I was talking about combo boxes. Is there any a method to hook an `onKeydown` event to the default dropdown box?

Comment: You should build your own form-widget as hooking event in current widgets are not encouraged and seems not stable. https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/widgets#form-class-definition

Answer (score 1):

Try adding "data tags" Select2 (dropdown) attribute to the field definition:

```
category: 
    type: dropdown
    attributes:
        data-tags: true
```

Also define method collecting category values in the relevant model:

```
public function getCategoryOptions($keyValue = null)
{
    $optList = Category::orderBy('title')->get()->lists('title', 'title');
    if (!is_null($keyValue))
    {
        $optList = [$keyValue => $keyValue] + $optList;
    }
    return $optList;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem because I need only the unique values as a suggestion. But the actual value should be a string and only one category per item.

Comment: So, this is not about category pivot relation but pure string attribute with ability to add it from select combo on the fly?

Comment: Yes that's what I want. Same table no pivot

Comment: OK, edited the answer with a clever workaround... :)